# Create a command line star rating with full and half stars from a float? Python 3

Tags: python, logic

So I'm working on a command line app that gets hotel details and one of these details is their "star rating". I could just list out the string that I get it as, but that's no fun, and I want the app to *really* look nice. So I wanted to create the appearance of the star rating myself.

Little did I know, this would probably require a little more math than I thought (it could even make a great interview question).

The details are:

- The data I am passing in looks like this: `3.7 stars`
- I want to get a closest estimate, in this 3.5 would suffice.
- I return it as a string that should look like "++-", where a "+" denotes a full star and a "-" denotes a half star

My code so far:

```
def format_hotel_rating(self, rating):
    rating_as_num = float(rating[:3])  # rating => "3.7 stars"

    for i in range(0, new_rating * 10):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            new_rating += "+"

        # still missing half star logic
```

My logic so far has been along these lines:

- take the decimal and multiply it by 10 (so it can be iterated over easier)
- For every 10th iteration, add a full star
- when there cannot be another multiple of 10, count *each* iteration between the last multiple of 10 and the final iteration
- *For e.g.* 10 (full star), 20 (full star), 30 (full star), *31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37*
- Then, determine whether `37` is closer to `35` or `40`. If it's closer to 35, then append a half star "-", otherwise if it's closer to 40, append a full star "+"

I have been trying to work it out in my head for hours (guess I can't even pass my own interview), and I have not developed any successful approaches.

How could I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you replace your last for loop by purely working in floating-point domain?

```
pure_rating = int(rating_as_num)
decimal_part = rating_as_num - pure_rating
final_score = "+" * pure_rating
if decimal_part >= 0.75:
   final_score += "+"
elif decimal_part >= 0.25:
   final_score += "-"
```

First line finds integer part of the rating (3.7 -> 3).

Second line finds decimal part by subtracting the two.  (3.7 - 3 -> 0.7)

Finally, you create `pure_rating` number of `"+"` characters first. And then add `"+"` or `"-"` depending on the decimal part (whether it's in `0.5-0.75` range or `0.75-0.99` range)

Comment: good,  explicit, but no need to use math.floor when int does the same(unless math is already imported then it makes no difference), then you dont need to convert it to int anyway when doing `'+' * pure_rating`

Comment: What about the `0.25-0.5` range? For eg., `3.4` is closest to `+++-`

Comment: Oh, do you need a half star or a no star in a `0.25-0.5` range? Changing 0.5 to 0.25 in comparison operator will solve the problem

Comment: Alright, so with a few adjustments, I can mark this as the correct answer. I ran your code and it certainly does this trick. All that needed to be changed was: `if decimal_path >= 0.75: final_score += "+"` and `elif decimal_path >= 0.25: final_score += "-"`. The signs just have to be the other way around when they are getting appended. Great answer! This also eliminated the need for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
def extract_rating_from_string(rating_string):
    """
    eg. rating_string = '3.7 stars'
    """
    return float(rating_string.split()[0])

def round_rating_to_half(rating):
    """
    Round to nearest half
    """
    return round(rating * 2) / 2

def get_rating_stars(rating_string):
    """
    Main function to return stars from string
    """
    full_star = '+'
    half_star = '-'
    rating_float = extract_rating_from_string(rating_string)
    rounded_rating = round_rating_to_half(rating_float)

    if divmod(rounded_rating, 1)[1] == 0.5:
        return int(rounded_rating)*full_star + half_star
    else:
        return int(rounded_rating)*full_star
```

Outputs:

```
>>> get_rating_stars('3.7 stars')
'+++-'
>>> get_rating_stars('3.1 stars')
'+++'
>>> get_rating_stars('4.9 stars')
'+++++'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a simple two liner:

```
a, b = divmod(rating, 1.0)
stars = int(a) * '+' + ('-' if b >= 0.5 else '')
```

Where `rating` is your value as float.

Edit: changed the numbers.

Comment: I edited the numbers. The other where spitting out the starts for `rating * 2`.

Comment: This doesn't take in to account rounding to the nearest `0.5`. For eg., a rating of `3.4` should get `+++-` as the output, but this code gives `+++`.

Answer (score -1):

```
rating = 3.5 #or whatever the rating is
for i in range(int(3.5)) #int truncates decimal... get "whole" stars
    print('+', end='')
decimal = rating % 1 #gets how much "partial star" left over
if decimal >= .7: #close enough to be full star
    print('+')
else:
    print('-')
```